# Bundle resources of all forms of one language in one folder in .net

Tags: localization, internationalization, globalization

We are in the process of localizing our windows forms application.

We are using the approach where we set the localizable property to true and generate one resx file for one locale.

The problem is we have 20 forms, each to be localized in 3 languages, so there are 60 resx files. Each form shows 3 resx files along with cs and designer and default resx file.

It would be if there was a neat way to bundle all the resource files of 20 forms in a language specific folder. How to do it?

Since .net generates one satellite assembly for one language, after the assembly is generated after build process, can I move/delete the resx file?

Comment: One solution is , Make localizable as true, do not generate any other resx files from VS IDE, instead open the resx file in winres, save as the specific culture. generate a resource files using resgen and compile to a satellite assembly using Al. Now place this dll in the appropriate directory struture (fr-FR ) in the folder where the executable is . For keeping the files in the repositary we can create a folder fr-FR in the application and place all the resx files in this folder. Any comments?

Comment: That's quite typical scenario. Some people are using specialized tools to do such tasks.